# Connecting to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:9999', transport: 'socket'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

Facing problem with debugging play framework app. It does not say that it disconnected or connected, just stays connecting, but debugging does not work:
Connecting to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:9999', transport: 'socket'

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?